# Apache Mina SFTP SftpSubsystem.Factory()

Tags: java, sftp, apache-mina

I am trying to setup a simple SFTP server using [Apache Mine SSHD v1.2.0](https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/index.html).

I have looked at several examples on the web E.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441969/apache-mina-sftp-example), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698274/apache-mina-sftp-server-side-channel-listener-for-incoming-files) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388036/how-to-handle-incoming-files-in-apache-mina-sshd-sftp-server-in-java).

However they **all** have the same line in common which I cannot get NetBeans to resolve.  NetBeans tells me that it cannot find `Factory` in `SftpSubsystem`.  The line in question looks as follows:

```
sftpServer.setSubsystemFactories (
    Arrays. <NamedFactory <Command >> asList (new SftpSubsystem.Factory ()));
```

My `main` looks something like the following:

```
SshServer sftpServer = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer ();
sftpServer.setPort (PORT);
sftpServer.setKeyPairProvider (new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider (new File("hostkey.ser")));
sftpServer.setSubsystemFactories (
     Arrays. <NamedFactory <Command >> asList (new SftpSubsystem.Factory ()));
sftpServer.setPasswordAuthenticator (new PasswordAuthenticator () {
    @Override
    public boolean authenticate (String username, String password, ServerSession session) {
       return true;
    }
});
sftpServer.start ();
while(true);
```

What am I missing?  I simply want to connect to a dummy SFTP server and list some directories and upload a file or two.  The thing is that I want to do this from inside an existing java application.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In recent versions of Apache SSHD, it's `SftpSubsystemFactory`:

```
sftpServer.setSubsystemFactories(
    Arrays.<NamedFactory<Command>>asList(new SftpSubsystemFactory()));
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am not sure why I couldn't find that but replacing my line with the one you provided sorted my problem out.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me.  All the examples on the internet had SftpSubsystem.Factory .  Ugh.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using version 2.6.0, and now you don't need to typecast. You can simply say:

```
sftpServer.setSubsystemFactories(Arrays.asList(new SftpSubsystemFactory()));
```

Comment: You can also use "Collections.singletonList" instead.